# Updated Kendo UI Grid values using jQuery does not update the passed back model

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui grid and I add a new row and then I update the new rows values like so...

```
function RespondToRequest(id, sequence) {

x = parseInt(sequence) + 1

var grid = $('#ParameterGrid_' + id + '').data("kendoGrid");
grid.addRow();

var tr = $('#ParameterGrid_' + id + ' tr:last');

$('#ParameterGrid_' + id + ' tr:last-child td:nth-child(1)').html(id);
$('#ParameterGrid_' + id + ' tr:last-child td:nth-child(1)').val(id);

$('#ParameterGrid_' + id + ' tr:last-child td:nth-child(2)').html(x);
$('#ParameterGrid_' + id + ' tr:last-child td:nth-child(2)').val(x);

$(".k-grid-Accept", "#ParameterGrid_" + id + "").hide();
$(".k-grid-Respond", "#ParameterGrid_" + id + "").hide();

}
```

but when I submit the new row with the updated data...

```
function SuggestNewParameter(id) {

var grid = $('#ParameterGrid_2').data("kendoGrid");
grid.saveChanges();
}
```

the 2 values are not updated in the posted model...

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ParameterGrid_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, RequestParameter requestparameter)
    {
        if (requestparameter != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var new_requestparameter = new RequestParameter
            {
                RequestId = requestparameter.RequestId,
                UserId = 1, //viewmodel.UserId,
                Sequence = requestparameter.Sequence + 1,
                Request_Response_Date = DateTime.Now,
                DateNeeded = requestparameter.DateNeeded,
                Duration = requestparameter.Duration,
                Frequency = requestparameter.Frequency,
                Comments = requestparameter.Comments,
                IsLatestEntry = true
            };

            db.RequestParameters.Add(new_requestparameter);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(new[] { requestparameter }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

how do I make the changes I made get caught in the model that is passed back?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not enough to manipulate the HTML - you have to update the underlying model!

Access the dataSource of the grid and add a new model, like this:

```
var newModel = {
    RequestId: id,
    Sequence: x
}

grid.dataSource.add(newModel);
grid.dataSource.sync(); // sync with server
```

The UI will be automatically updated and all. :)